# Confusion about 1- vs 2-tailed tests for feature selection by hypothesis testing

Tags: machine-learning, hypothesis-testing, bayesian, feature-selection, naive-bayes

> Suppose $x_i\ (i=1,2,...,N)$ be attribute values for $N$ samples from
> class $W_1$ with mean $\mu_1 $ and $y_i\ (i=1,2,...,N)$ be attribute
> values for $N$ samples from class $W_2$ with mean $\mu_2 $.

> For feature selection using hypothesis testing, why we should define $H_0 =\mu_1 -\mu_2=0 $

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118798/discussion-on-question-by-lisa-m-confusion-about-1-vs-2-tailed-tests-for-featur).

Comment: I agree with the book that (A) is correct.  I'm pretty sure the TA is just wrong here. That happens. You'll probably have to talk to them to find out what their thinking was.

Comment: @gung-ReinstateMonica I think if the mean is not same, option (B) is the choice. isnt it?

Comment: @JohnatanMorian, yes, that's right.

Comment: @gung-ReinstateMonica please see the last two slide on Page 1 (one) from this https://www2.newpaltz.edu/~liush/ST/ch10.pdf

Comment: challenging question....

Comment: @gung-ReinstateMonica would you please see my asnwer?

Comment: @LisaM are you prepared to provide the bounty to an answer?

Answer (score 1):

This is one thought that $(B)$ is true:

You have two classes $Z=0, 1$ and usually we classify such that $P(Z=1| X) >0.5$. You need to choose a feature that increase the $P(Z=1|feature)$.

I think if you assume **normality** and use **LDA** (I mean assume variance of the features different  classes are equal), then you should be able to relate the problem to the mean of the features. I also think 2 is the only correct answer if you look at the problem this way.

Suppose $P(Z=1| feature) =$ a $\mu_{feature} + b$ with $a>0$. Then $P(Z=1|x) > P(Z=1|Y)$  if $\mu_x > \mu_y$.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your solution here.  Let's just talk about a single dimension for ease of exposition.  Following notes from *an introduction to statistical learning with R*, LDA will assign a label of class 1 when $2x(\mu_1 - \mu_2) > (\mu^2_1 - \mu^2_2)$.  This requirement does not make any assumptions re: the difference in the sign of means as per OP's question.  Can you provide additional details? Additionally, if your expression $P(Z=1\vert feature)$ is indeed a probability, it does not appear to be bounded.

Answer (score 0):

Option B is false.

I'm assuming the purpose of feature selection is to identify predictors which help distinguish between classes.  Ostensibly, if two classes have an observed difference in class conditional expectation which is larger than what could reasonably happen under chance + test assumptions, then that predictor should be used to construct a model.

Assume that the sign of $\mu_1 - \mu_2$ did matter, and assume further that we would select feature $x$ because we reject the null of the test.  The labels of the classes are arbitrary, so permute them switching $W_1$ to $W_2$ and vice versa.  It is important to stress that nothing changes about the data itself, only the class labels.

Under this permutation, the sign of $\mu_1 - \mu_2$ would flip, and we would fail to reject the null and hence not select $x$ as a feature.  That isn't a desirable property of the procedure.  What features we select should not depend on arbitrary labels.

Its very clear here that your TA has made an error, and if the TA is insistent they are correct then they would have to deal with the dilemma I've outlined here: either the procedure depends on arbitrary labels, or the sign of the difference is irrelevant (unless we've made it relevant, in which case the question here is moot and the exam question is to blame).

You've already provided a reputable source, so I don't think additional sources are needed.  You're right, the answer should be A.

Comment: so would you please tell me what is wrong with my answer? another view to this problem

Comment: @JohnatanMorian Immediately I see that you make some assumptions about a) classification rules, b) normality of the data, and c) the method of classification.  You may be right, I haven't taken the time to check, but if you are right then you are right under a very narrow set of circumstances, none of which were mentioned in the question.  It isn't a knock against you, I just don't see how this generalizes immediately.  Can you expand your solution to be more general?

Comment: so I'm not expert. would you please check my assumption? because you are expert in statistics. under my assumption is it right conclusion or not? if no I remove my answer. would you please check my inference using the mentioned assumption?

Comment: @JohnatanMorian. Sure. Will check once I get home

Comment: really appreciated.

Comment: @LisaM Nothing in your question seems to refer to P(Z=1).  I'm not sure what Z is in this context.  The question is about differences in sample means conditional on the class label, not about probabilities of belonging to one class over another.

Comment: @LisaM You're going to have to update your own question to make it more clear.  The way it is presently phrased, B is not the answer.  I can't do anything until your question is coherent with the arguments you're stating here.

Comment: @LisaM That is not feature selection.  Feature selection is a class of procedures designed to pick which variables we should use in models which *then compute probabilities of belonging to various classes*.  I suggest you revisit the material you are studying and make sure you understand the difference.